# Entity Framework Core Multiple Foreign Keys to the same Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core-2.2

For example I have these 2 Entities

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EmployeeGroup> EmployeesGroups { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessState
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string PendingEntity { get; set; }
    public string ApprovingEntity { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Process> Processes { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have

```
PendingEntity
ApprovingEntity
```

to be foreign keys to the Group Entity.

```
int PendingEntity - Group.Id
int ApprovingEntity - Group.Id
```

How can i describe this on my model?

Comment: change their data type here instead of `string` use `Group`

Comment: this worked, it needs 2 navigation properties apparently